# Some Cells on UITableView won't auto-resize

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am experiencing a very strange phenomenon. I am using the AutomaticDimension function on my tableview and for some odd reason it works on all of my cells except for 3. All of my cells have the exact same constraints which is the weird part. I have tried changing the constraints on the cells but it appears that they are being ignored. Any insight would be great. I make sure to call the auto dimension function in viewdidload.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.TableView.dataSource = self

    TableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
    TableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Here is one of the classes that is not working:

```
class foursleepCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var foursleepLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var foursleepScale: UISegmentedControl!

var delegate: foursleepCellToController?

@IBAction func foursleepValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if let delegate = delegate {
        let indexPath = delegate.indexOfChangedfoursleepCell(at: self)
        delegate.savefoursleepCellResponse(at: indexPath, response: foursleepScale.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
}
}
```

Attached are images of constraints and output:

[Label Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFIl7.png)

[Segmented Control Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6boD.png)

[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvNDd.png)

[Working Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDXMW.png)

Comment: I've been having what may be the same problem (asked a similar question of couple of days ago but have not gotten an answer). Based on your pictures, some constraints just don't exist at runtime. I'm guessing that is the root of the issue - without the constraints from top-to-bottom, the auto-resizing can't work.

Comment: Can you try to set estimatedRowHeight  = 40 ?

Comment: I tried that. Didn't fix anything

Comment: if you using UITableViewAutomaticDimension I think its not necessary to give estimatedRowHeight then as UITableViewAutomaticDimension is working over your estimatedRowHeight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the way you are trying to set the cell to automatically resize, it is just the fact the the top-to-bottom constraints that are required for that resizing to happen are not present at runtime. Apparently this is something that can happen sometimes in Xcode - try creating a new table view cell and setting up all the views and constraints again from scratch. Copying and pasting the table view cell into a new cell and working from the copy did not fix it for me - it behaved exactly the same. But setting it up fresh did the trick.